# Create java subtypes using diffent builders

Tags: java, oop, builder, solid-principles, inversion

I have a class `Foo` which has a subtype `SubFoo`, and I have a builder `FooBuilder` which creates the `Foo` objects.

This is how `Foo` looks like:

```
class Foo {
    protected Object superField;
}
```

the `SubFoo`

```
class SubFoo extends Foo {
     private Object subField;
}
```

```
class FooBuilder {
 protected Object superField;

 withSuperField(Object field){
   this.superField = field;
 }

 Foo build(){
   return new Foo(superField);
 }
}
```

```
class SubFooBuilder extends FooBuilder{
 protected Object subField;

 withSubField(Object field){
   this.subField = field;
 }

 Foo build(){
   return new SubFoo(superField, subField);
 }
}
```

and there is some code that creates an adequate builder depending on some criterion.

```
FooBuilder create(){
 return someCriterion ? new FooBuilder() : new SubFooBuilder();
}
```

Is there a way or changes to be made so that the builder's client code creates a `Foo` or `SubFoo` objects without knowing which builder it uses? Because I don't wanna break `Dependency inversion` principle.

Comment: How do you use `Foo` and `SubFoo`? Which methods do they have in common?

Comment: they are used in a generic  converter later

Answer (score 1):

I think you want an [Abstract factory](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abstract_factory_pattern)

First of all you need to declare an interface for the `Foo` object, let's call it `Foo`:

```java
public interface Foo {
    public void fooMethod();
}
```

Second, provide as many implementations of the interface as you wish, for example `FooImpl1` and `FooImpl2` (relevant to your `Foo` and `SubFoo`)

```java
public class FooImpl1 implements Foo {
    public void fooMethod() {
        //first implementation goes here
    }
}

//NOTE: this class can also extend FooImpl1, if you wish
public class FooImpl2 implements Foo {
    public void fooMethod() {
        //second implementation goes here
    }
}
```

Next, declare an interface for the `Foo` factory:

```java
public interface FooFactory {
    public Foo build();
}
```

Now you can create as many factories as you wish:

```java
public class FooFactoryImpl1 implements FooFactory {
    public FooImpl1 build() {
        // create and return FooImpl1
    }
}

public class FooFactoryImpl2 implements FooFactory {
    public FooImpl2 build() {
        // create and return FooImpl2
    }
}
```

With this approach your client code depends on the interfaces only. You can provide it any implementation of `FooFactory`, so the client does not know which factory exactly is being used, as well as the real implementation of the `Foo` object.